# How to start simulation from a negative frame?

Tags: animation, physics, cloth-simulation

I have checked:

[image]

Allow negative frame is on.

[image]

Use preview range is on.

[image]

Cloth modifier's start frame is -30.

But when I press play, the animation still starts from Frame 0. What did I miss?

Comment: I guess you need to bake the simulation

Comment: @moonboots there is no simulation to bake. When I press play it jumps to Frame 0. No animation/cache/simulated data between Frame -30 to Frame -1.

Comment: I mean I'm not sure it will play unless you bake

Comment: Uh really, let me try it... I always thought the process should be cahce -> bake.

Comment: yes there should be a Bake button in the Physics > Cloth > Cache. Have you tried? If it still doesn't work, maybe share your file?